# ¿Cómo ajustar automáticamente las columnas de un DataGridView?

Tags: c#

Lo que quiero hacer es que mi columna `Descripción` se muestre completa en la pantalla.

En la imagen se muestra cortada y quiero lograr que se acople con todo el datagrid.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la [propiedad](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizecolumnsmode(v=vs.110).aspx) `DataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode`, a lo cual le asignas un valor [DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnsmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
miDataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

También puedes usar el [Método](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms158594(v=vs.110).aspx) DataGridView.AutoResizeColumns (DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode)

```
miDataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
```

Answer (score 0):

esto te puede ayudar un poco :

```
    this.DataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
    this.DataGridView1.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
    this.DataGridView1.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez podrías usar algo como esto, no es perfecto y pensaba en optimizarlo pero me ha funcionado bien. Lo que hace es que le mandas porcentajes y los nombres de las columnas y las ajusta a los porcentajes incluso cuando la ventana cambia de tamaño, toma en cuenta el ancho del slider de la derecha y el RowHeader de la izquierda si es visible. Sólo tendrás que hacerle unos cambios porque está diseñado para un RadGridView de Telerik.

## AutoAjustarColumnas

```
    private static double[] ValidarPorcentajes(int columnas, double[] porcentajes)
    {
        if (porcentajes == null)
            return null;
        else if (columnas > porcentajes.Length)
        {
            List<double> values = new List<double>(porcentajes);
            double lastValue = porcentajes[porcentajes.Length - 1];
            int diferencia = columnas - porcentajes.Length;
            for (int j = columnas - diferencia; j < columnas; j++)
                values.Add(lastValue);
            return values.ToArray();
        }
        return porcentajes;
    }
    private static int[] CalcularPorcentajes(double[] porcentajes, int width)
    {
        try
        {
            int[] c = new int[porcentajes.Length];

            int i = -1;
            foreach (double p in porcentajes)
                c[++i] = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(width * (p / 100)));

            int tWidth = c.Sum();

            if (tWidth > width)
                c[0] -= tWidth - width;
            else if (tWidth < width)
                c[0] += width - tWidth;
            return c;
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }
    private static int ObtenerAnchoDeTrabajo(RadGridView gvw, int columnas, out bool offset)
    {
        try
        {
            int originalHeight, rowHeaderColumnSpace, height = 0, scrollSize = 17;

            originalHeight = gvw.GridViewElement.TableElement.RowHeaderColumnWidth;
            rowHeaderColumnSpace = gvw.MasterTemplate.ShowRowHeaderColumn ? originalHeight - columnas : 1 - columnas;
            if (!Convert.ToBoolean(gvw.Tag))
            {
                int rowHeigth = gvw.GridViewElement.TableElement.RowHeight;
                height = (gvw.Rows.Count * rowHeigth) + (gvw.SummaryRowsBottom.Count * originalHeight) + (gvw.SummaryRowsTop.Count * originalHeight) + originalHeight + scrollSize;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (GridViewDataRowInfo row in gvw.Rows)
                    if (row.Tag != null)
                    {
                        int value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Tag);
                        height += value > row.Height ? value : row.Height;
                        row.Tag = row.Height;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row.Tag = row.Height;
                        height += row.Height;
                    }
                height += (gvw.SummaryRowsBottom.Count * originalHeight) + (gvw.SummaryRowsTop.Count * originalHeight) + originalHeight;
            }
            offset = height > gvw.Height;
            return gvw.Width - (offset ? rowHeaderColumnSpace + scrollSize : rowHeaderColumnSpace);
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }
    public static void CambiarAnchoColumnas(this RadGridView gvw, string[] nombreColumnas, params double[] porcentajes)
    {
        gvw.AutoSize = false;

        foreach (string nombre in nombreColumnas)
            if (!gvw.Columns.Contains(nombre))
                throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("La columna \"{0}\" no se encuentra en la GridView", nombre));
        try
        {
            if (gvw.Tag == null)
            {
                EventHandler handler = delegate
                {
                    try { gvw.CambiarAnchoColumnas(nombreColumnas, porcentajes); }
                    catch { throw; }
                };
                gvw.SizeChanged += handler;
                gvw.RowHeightChanged += (s, e) => { gvw.VerticalScrollState = ScrollState.AutoHide; };
                gvw.ColumnWidthChanged += (s, e) => { gvw.HorizontalScrollState = ScrollState.AutoHide; };
                gvw.Tag = gvw.AutoSizeRows;
                if (gvw.AutoSizeRows)
                {
                    PaintEventHandler enter = null;
                    enter = (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        if (gvw.IsDisplayed)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                handler(gvw, e);
                                gvw.Paint -= enter;
                            }
                            catch { throw; }
                        }
                    };
                    gvw.Paint += enter;
                    return;
                }
            }
            bool offset;
            porcentajes = ValidarPorcentajes(nombreColumnas.Length, porcentajes);
            int width = ObtenerAnchoDeTrabajo(gvw, nombreColumnas.Length, out offset);
            int[] c = CalcularPorcentajes(porcentajes, width);

            int i = -1;
            foreach (string columna in nombreColumnas)
                gvw.Columns[columna].Width = c[++i];

            gvw.BackColor = gvw.TableElement.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            if (offset)
            {
                gvw.HorizontalScrollState = ScrollState.AlwaysHide;
                gvw.VerticalScrollState = ScrollState.AlwaysShow;
            }
            else
                gvw.HorizontalScrollState = gvw.VerticalScrollState = ScrollState.AlwaysHide;
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }
    public static void WrapText(this RadGridView gvw, bool value)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var c in gvw.Columns)
                if (c.IsVisible)
                    c.WrapText = value;
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }
```

Y puedes utilizarlo así:

```
gdvReporte.CambiarAnchoColumnas(gdvReporte.Columns.Select(c => c.Name).ToArray(), 43, 8, 11, 13, 25);
```